# .htaccess rule to overwrite friendly url behavior

Tags: .htaccess

I am using a CMS called Vivvo, and vivvo comes with a .htaccess file from default with the following rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)(\.html|\.htm)$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)(\.rss|\.atom|\.txt)$ index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php [L]
```

There's a folder called `book/` in my webroot that I need to be accessible from the outside. However whenever I type www.mydomain.com/book vivvo sends me to the customized 404 error page.

What rule can I use, in order to make the web server to ignore the "RewriteCond" and make users go to the right directory?

I tried this with no success:

```
 RewriteRule book/ book/index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/book/"
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]
# the rest of your rules...
```